# Does it exists any $n(n>2)$ dimensional orthogonal matrix with exactly one zero in each row(column)? How to construct a general one if it exists?

Tags: matrices

I am wondering whether there exists a $n(n>2)$ dimensional matrix with exactly one 0 in each row(column), I will be appreciated if anyone can provide a solid example for general $n(n>2)$ or give a proof that it does not exist, thanks!

Sorry for misdescribing my question, I am asking whether that statement holds for general $n(n>2)$. Or if the statement holds true, is there any general methodology to construct this kind of matrix for any $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about
$$\frac1{\sqrt3}\pmatrix{0&1&1&1\\1&0&1&-1\\1&-1&0&1\\1&1&-1&0}?$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am still wondering whether there is a general answer to this question. Since the statement is false when $n=3$, maybe there will be some general conclusion to this(i.e., the statement holds for even $n$ and it does not hold for odd $n$.). I have been doing the calculation for a week and will update if I find anything interesting. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: I suspect $n=3$ is the only exceptional case. Alas, for general $n\ge5$ I don't know a way of writing down an explicit example. @SimonZhai

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help!